# Wrapping image_data_generator.flow_from_dataframe in tf.data pipeline.. what step should I take?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, input, tf.data.dataset

```
train_generator=datagen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe=train_df, #directory=data_path, 
                                            x_col="Path", y_col="feature_string", seed = 42, classes = chexpert_targets,
                                            class_mode="categorical", target_size=(image_size,image_size), batch_size=32, subset = "training")

validation_generator = datagen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe=train_df, #directory=data_path, 
                                                   x_col="Path", y_col="feature_string", seed = 42, classes = chexpert_targets,
                                                      class_mode="categorical", target_size=(image_size,image_size), batch_size=16, subset = "validation")
    
test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe=valid_only_df, #directory=data_path, 
                                                  target_size=(image_size,image_size),class_mode='categorical',
                                                  batch_size=1, shuffle=False, classes = chexpert_targets,
                                                  x_col="Path", y_col="feature_string")
    
x_col, y_col = next(train_generator)
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    lambda: train_generator, 
    output_types=(tf.float32, tf.float32), 
    output_shapes=([32,320,320,3], [32,14])
)
```

I am trying to wrap the `image_data_generator.flow_from_dataframe` using `tf.data` but I am finding difficulties, I would really appreciate some help?

Comment: Please format your code properly using ```

Comment: Check it out now.